# How to play swf file through memory stream in Web browser in c#.net?

Tags: c#, memory, webbrowser-control

```
 public void InitFlashMovie(AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash flashObj, byte[] swfFile)
        {
            GC.Collect();

                using (MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stm))
                    {
                        /* Write length of stream for AxHost.State */
                        writer.Write(8 + swfFile.Length);
                        /* Write Flash magic 'hohoho' */
                        writer.Write(0x55665566);
                        /* Length of swf file */
                        writer.Write(swfFile.Length);
                        writer.Write(swfFile);
                        stm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        /* 1 == IPeristStreamInit */
                        flashObj.OcxState = new AxHost.State(stm, 1, false, null);
                        writer.Dispose();
                        stm.Dispose();
                    }
                }

}
```

Here I want WebBrowser instead of AxshockwaveFlash ,please anyone answer for this .I need to run .swf file in web Browser so if you know the answer please post.

Comment: Why not have an HTML page that embeds the SWF file locally and just navigate to that?

Comment: Yeah its fine @ Luke Park. If I want to play many swf file (by clicking next and previous)we cant create HTML for each file know.